# Find and replace based on criteria with Google Apps Scripts Code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have two Google Sheets housed in the same Spreadsheet object, for reference I'll refer to them as Data and Change-Log.

```
Data Sheet

ID   Country   Attribute   Value
1    USA       X           100
2    RUS       X           77
3    MEX       Y           32
4    GER       Z           111
...
```

```
Change-Log Sheet

Country   Attribute   Value
USA       X           84
GER       Z           97
```

```
Updated Data Sheet

ID   Country   Attribute   Value
1    USA       X           84
2    RUS       X           77
3    MEX       Y           32
4    GER       Z           97
...
```

Currently I am pulling into the Data sheet via an API, which is cleared and updated monthly.

Ideally I would like to write some sort of helper function that can query the Data sheet for entries shared between the two sheets and overwrite values in the Data sheet with the corresponding value from the Change-Log.

In the example above, I would want to query where the Country and Indicator variables are the same, then compare the Value variable and give preference to the Change-Log.Value entry by overwriting this value into the Data sheet where appropriate.

Comment: Can you show any work you have already tried and any logged errors or issues?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Ideally I would like to write some sort of helper function that can parse through the Data sheet and update the value based upon shared criteria from both sheets. I would like to make this exclusively with JS code, and trigger the function after the monthly updating of data from the API I am using.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Answer (score 0):

We have a very little information on how your sheets look and what are you trying to do.
You can do something like this:

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4);
  const dataValues = dataRange.getValues(); // Get at once, faster execution

  const changeLogSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Change-Log");
  const replacements = changeLogSheet.getRange(2, 1, changeLogSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues(); // Faster

  const newValues = [];
  dataValues.forEach(row => {
    const replacementValue = getReplacementValue_(row[1], row[2], replacements);
    newValues.push([row[0], row[1], row[2], (replacementValue ? replacementValue : row[3])]);
  });

  dataRange.setValues(newValues); // Faster
}

function getReplacementValue_(country, attribute, replacements) {
  const matchingRows = replacements.filter(row => row[0] == country && row[1] == attribute);
  return matchingRows.length > 0 ? matchingRows[0][2] : null;
}
```

I'm not sure if you want to overwrite all the data each time, or start at some row.

Note 1: Stack Overflow community will be able to help you more if your question is in the form of "here is my goal and code so far, these are the errors and problems". If you ask "how to do something" we won't be able to help you that much.

Note 2: If some answer helps you, upvote/accept it. If not, edit your question to provide more information. In this case it would be good if you can make a copy of your sheet (if data is sensitive then replace with mock data) and share it with anyone on the internet and post a link in your question. Something like "Data" sheet, "Change Log" sheet and "Desired Data" sheet.